# How to write a conditional/if statement to be true if an object is in the array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

What i want to do in this conditional is make sure the object in the array
(neighbors of the middle cell) is physically inside the array, so i thought i would just make the third variable in the constructor (age) equal to zero, thinking if it cant find that instance variable it wouldn't go further. but it gives me an out of bounds -1 exception and i don't know how to re write it to avoid that.
(I apologize if this isnt enough detail, i can provide more, just ask)

So heres the part of my code im stuck on:

```
for (int x = 0; x < Grid.columns; x++) {

    for (int y = 0; y < Grid.rows; y++) {

        int nCount = 0;
        int hCount = 0;
        //check neighbors
        for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                //check if valid and identity
                //STUCK HERE--->   if(i !=0 && j !=0)
                if (board[x + i][y + j].age == 0) {
                    nCount++;
                    if (board[x + i][y + j].getPreviousValue() == 0)
                        hCount++;
                }

            }
        }
        board[x][y].setCurrentValue(hCount / nCount, (nCount - hCount) / nCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: for inside for inside for inside for ... and then if inside if ... i would suggest rewriting it

Comment: this code is very confusing :S

Comment: [If you need more than 3 levels of indentation...](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/52685/if-you-need-more-than-3-levels-of-indentation-youre-screwed)

Comment: i dont know why you are initializing your declared variables in the loop with -1 , if you dont know, your variables wont iterate (i++) unless the code block of the loop finishes execution, so it will stay -1 in the first iteration, this may cause the Exception

Answer (score 3):

Your problem are the 'edge-cells' of your grid, since you access indices outside the array. (like -1 and array.length). For a sound solution you would have to check for this conditions.

```
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {

            int neighbor_x = x + i;
            int neighbor_y = y + j;

            if (neighbor_x < 0 || neighbor_x >= board.length) {
              // Out of Grid
            }

            if (neighbor_y < 0 || neighbor_y >= board[neighbor_x].length) {
              // Out of Grid
            }

            if (board[neighbor_x][neighbor_y].age == 0) {
                nCount++;
                if (board[x + i][y + j].getPreviousValue() == 0)
                    hCount++;
            }

        }
    }
```

Another possibility would be to simply catch the exception. However, this can be considered bad style. I would not recommend using this code:

```
for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
        try {
            if (board[x + i][y + j].age == 0) {
                nCount++;
                if (board[x + i][y + j].getPreviousValue() == 0)
                    hCount++;
                }
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            // Here you know that the exception occured.
            //
            // In this particular case we will not write any code,
            // since the proper handling of this exception is to move
            // on to the next cell.
        }
    }
}
```

And as a remark: style is always subjective, but 6 levels of nesting is usually not good.

Comment: how would i catch the exception, i have never done that before but i am familiar with the concept, would you mind providing the code verbatim? thanks man

Comment: I regret even mentioning the 'catch the exception' solution. However, I've provided an example.

Comment: for the "//out of grid" part, i dont know what ti insert here, this was my problem in the first place, how do i tell it its out of the grid?

Comment: Well, that depends on *what you want to happen*. You don't have to tell somebody you're out of grid. It's just your responsibility not to access nonexisting array indices. So the "out of grid part" is what **you** have to handle. If you just want to skip the current cell - identified by x and y - you could just say `continue;`. (Please read the doc if you don't know what `continue` does.)

Comment: @user2760010 Have you tried `continue`? Did it solve your problem? What do you want to happen in case the element is not in the array?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have array's with a negative value, in your case -1. Arrays start at 0, so with `i` equaling -1 & `j` equaling -1, you are getting that error.  You are adding -1 to 0, thus getting -1 for for your array selection. Keep the numbers positive.

I'm also not sure what you are trying to do here. I mean where else would the element be if it isn't in the array? If you are wondering if the item is in the array, there are array methods you can use to see if a particular value is in an array. If you are trying to determine if a particular value exists, then that's one things, I'm just not clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: no no , i am emulating conways game of life and that part is checking the adjacent neighbors of each cell, the problem is when it checks the edges, or corners of the array as there are no indexes to the left/ right of a corner or up/down.

Comment: If that's the case, the the left should be 0, middle 1, and right 2. If you use that as the index, you can do your checks :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to do some bounds checking.

Using your example, on the very first time inside the fourth(!) for loop, you have `x=0`, `y=0`, `i=-1`, and `j=-1`.  This means you're trying to access `board[-1][-1]`, which obviously doesn't exist.  One (not necessarily optimal) way to fix this would be to use another `if` statement that checks for out-of-bounds conditions, such as `if ((x+i) >= 0) && ((x+1) < Grid.columns) && ((y+j) >= 0 && (y+j) < Grid.Rows)`.

The problem is not with the `if(i !=0 && j !=0)` part.. it's with the fact that your indexes go out of bounds.

And as an aside, as has been mentioned in the comments and other answers, having a fourth nested `for` loop is not a great idea, and can easily lead to memory or run-time performance problems.  In this particular case, since you're checking at most eight points (four if you uncomment the `!=0` if statement) with your third and fourth nested for loops, you could try actually enumerating just those eight (or four).

And as another aside, if you have nested `if` statements, like so:

```
if(test1)
    if(test2)
        doSomething();
```

then you can try combining them into a single if statement:

```
if(test1 && test2)
    doSomething();
```

This won't always work (`else` statements come to mind), but it can help to make your code readable.

Comment: Honestly having a third `for` loop isn't a great idea. Nested `for` loops makes the run-time grow exponentially.

Comment: i think this is exactly what i was looking for, a way of catching the exception or telling the program not to check if its out of bounds. will get back to you. appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

with all this complicated code that i feel i cant understand what goes where, what i understand is that you want to deal with an object in an array in the second dimension, you can do something like this :

```
    int[][][] ints = {              
                {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},  // dimension 0
                {{},{},{7,8,9}}     // dimension 1
                };

    for(int i = 0;i<ints.length;i++){
        for(int t = 0;t<ints[i].length;t++){
            // check if the middle Dimension array is initialized
            if((ints[i][t] != null) && ints[i][t].length > 0){
                for(int z = 0;z<ints[i][t].length;z++){
                    System.out.println("Dimension "+i+"-"+t+" : "+ints[i][t][z]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Result
        Dimension 0-0 : 1
        Dimension 0-0 : 2
        Dimension 0-0 : 3
        Dimension 0-1 : 4
        Dimension 0-1 : 5
        Dimension 0-1 : 6
        Dimension 1-2 : 7   // skipped the empty dimentions 1-0,1-1
        Dimension 1-2 : 8
        Dimension 1-2 : 9
        */
```

but a piece of advice, i think that starting your loop with -1 is the cause of this ... please try to start your for loop with "0" ... your code is trying to find an element of index -1 in the array, which causes the Exception

you can catch this Exception and "eat/skip" it, but this is a bad idea