# how to write a conditional telling java that the array index is invalid

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

(this is a 2d array filled with objects) So the places marked "//Out of Grid" is where I don't know how to tell java that the index its looking for is not in the grid and to move on.

A basic over view of what im trying to accomplish is go thru each cell starting`[0][0]` and check all of its adjacent neighbors, as for the first check its neighbors would be `[0][1]`,`[1][0]`, and `[1][1]`. and then if the age of the object in the index is 0, do something..

```
for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {

        int neighbor_x = x + i;
        int neighbor_y = y + j;

        if (neighbor_x < 0 || neighbor_x >= board.length) {
          // Out of Grid
        }

        if (neighbor_y < 0 || neighbor_y >= board[neighbor_x].length) {
          // Out of Grid
        }

        if (board[neighbor_x][neighbor_y].age == 0) {
            nCount++;
            if (board[x + i][y + j].getPreviousValue() == 0)
                hCount++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: hmm didnt seem to work

Comment: Odd, what's not working?

Comment: I should also add that you're not skipping when i==0 and j==0, a cell is not it's own neighbor.

Comment: yeah i got that part down the out of bounds is what i need help with

Comment: Can you update your code listing? I have almost the exact same code for some neighbor checking and it works fine with the continue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a conditional/if statement to be true if an object is in the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926946/how-to-write-a-conditional-if-statement-to-be-true-if-an-object-is-in-the-array)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to perform some operations, you can simply leave them out.

Out of bound exception can occur in the case where `neighbor_x < 0` and `neighbor_y >=0`, when the second statement is being ran, the first condition is verified and the second throws an exception. You can simply use the only condition that matters

```
for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {

        int neighbor_x = x + i;
        int neighbor_y = y + j;

        if ((neighbor_x >=0 && neighbor_x < board.length) && 
             (neighbor_y >= 0 && neighbor_y < board[neighbor_x].length) &&
             board[neighbor_x][neighbor_y].age == 0 ) {
            nCount++;
            if (board[x + i][y + j].getPreviousValue() == 0)
            hCount++;
        }

     }
}
```

If this ever throws an exception, then just separate the conditions comme suite

```
 if ( neighbor_x >=0 && neighbor_x < board.length )
         if(neighbor_y >= 0 && neighbor_y < board[neighbor_x].length)
                 if(board[neighbor_x][neighbor_y].age == 0 )
```

Comment: if its the index is not on the grid, i want to leave it out, only count up (nCount) indexes that are. , tried this still gives out of bounds exception -1.